# Color picker and pallete suddenly missing in texture paint

Tags: texture-painting

While working suddenly color picker and pallete suddenly missing in texture paint. How to make them reappear?

Blender 2.93
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the current brush set to Soften, which does not use colour. Switch the brush to Draw or Fill to bring back the colour picker.

[image]